# ¿Como puedo mostrar el nombre al enviar un correo en mi formulario?

Tags: php, formularios

Descripcion:
Al enviar correo en mi formulario quiero que aparezca el nombre al recibirlo pero no me deja enviarlo si lo coloco en mi codigo,si quito esa variable si me deja enviarlo y aparece el mensaje de que a sido enviado pero necesito que se muestre esa informacion para la empresa en este caso lo contacte

2.Codigo PHP

```
<?php

$empresa = "example@gmail.com"; #correo a donde llegara

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    if (!empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['asunto']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['msg'])) {
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $msg = $_POST['msg'];
        $header = "From: $email" . "\r\n"; #correo de quien lo envia
        $header.= "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n";
        $header.= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
        $mail = @mail($empresa,$asunto,$nombre, $msg,$header); #informacion a mostrarse cunado tenga el correo
        if ($mail) {
            echo"<h2>Enviado exitosamente</h2>";
        }else{
            echo "<h2>No se a enviado correctamente</h2>";
            print_r($_POST);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

3.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Formulario de contacto</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="nombre" required>
    <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email">
    <input type="text" placeholder="asunto" name="asunto">
    <textarea placeholder="mensaje" name="msg"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar">
</form>
<?php
include("contacto.php");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola! Disculpa; no trabajo a diario en PHP hace un rato, pero sé que la función estándar no tiene un campo para _el nombre_ que quieres añadir ahí. La pregunta es: estás usando algún framework? Lo otro, no te da lío poner en el from el email del que envía? Lo digo porque los servidores suelen ser muy celosos y rechazar cuentas que no sean del propio servidor

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo,no estoy usando un framework por ahora posterior de que este formulario funcione lo adaptare a Angular,no tengo problema con el email que mencionas el formulario funciona solo si no agrego la variable de nombre,si la pongo no me deja enviarlo ,puede que sea la funcion el problema.

Comment: Es que no sé por qué intentas poner el nombre como parámetro de `mail` de acuerdo a la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). Deberías manipular el texto del mail (`$msg`?) o algún otro texto en el mensaje

Comment: Ya lo solucione gracias es lo que decias

Comment: Puedes poner tu respuesta (aca debajo, en _Tu respuesta_) con el código que te funcionó. En un rato, inclusive, puedes marcarla como aceptada!